# HttpClient - PostAsync doesn’t return

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, async-await, microsoft-graph-api

Does anyone know why HttpClient - PostAsync doesn’t return. It just does nothing. I have had it working occasionally especially for one off posts but it seems sometimes to not do anything especially under load and it doesn't throw an exception which of course makes my code unreliable and hard to debug.

I have tried adding ConfigureAwait(false) It makes not difference.

I suspect the Task is failing to 'pack'

This is in a core 3.0 console app run on macOS Catalina using visual studio code

This code is pretty much copied from Microsoft's documentation and I’m calling Microsoft Graph when posting.

```
public static async Task PostAsync(HttpClient httpClient, string url, string token, HttpContent content, Action<JObject> processResult, ILogger log)
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        // content.Headers.Clear();
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
                processResult(result);
            }
            else
            {
                var errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                log.LogError(errorContent);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of the calling code

```
public async Task SendInvitation(string token, Invitation invitation, ILogger logger)
{
    var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invitation), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    await HttpHelpers.PostAsync(
        Client,
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations",
        token,
        stringContent,
        result => logger.LogInformation(DebugHelpers.Print(result)),
        logger);
}
```

**Answered (Sort of)**

If I change

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
```

to

```
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

It seems to work but it's slow because what I'm doing is using blocking code. I think this is a quirk of core 3 on macOS. I don't like that this is happening.

**More Info**

I'm doing a lot of looping.

It seems that if I put all the things I'm awaiting in a taskList it behaves properly.

```
\\ Pseudo Code
var taskList = new List<Task>();

foreach(var thing in things){
  taskList.Add(HttpHelpers.PostAsync(...things));
}

await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```

Comment: What do you mean with it doesn't return? What is the value of response?

Comment: How long do you wait before terminating? I just wonder if you would get a timeout exception eventually. I can say with confidence that `HttpClient` does work.

Comment: @tubakaya there is no response it literally does not return

Comment: @Crowcoder the program ends having not done any posts

Comment: So does the process exit then? Or it hangs?

Comment: @tubakaya it exits. when I put a breakpoint on the line after postasync it never reaches it. the rest of the code in the app runs and it exits. all the getasync code in the app works btw

Comment: It might be an issue of how this method is called as a whole. Can you add how the PostAsync(HttpClient ...,string,......) method is called?

Comment: @tubakaya see edit

Comment: I know you said it doesn't throw an exception but are you sure? It could be swallowed. Put a break point on `throw` if you haven't already tried that.

Comment: Are you saying that `HttpClient.PostAsync()` never returns? Or are you saying that `HttpHelpers.PostAsync()` never returns?

Comment: @JohnWu HttpClient.PostAsync()

Comment: @Crowcoder it doesn't hit the throw

Comment: If it never returns, how is the program exiting? Is there an exception being thrown?

Comment: @JohnWu It is async non blocking code

Comment: So upper in the code execution path, there might be a method that doesn't support async usage. If you then use async as part of it, things get pretty mysterious just like process exiting that you describe. Take for example  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args)
                            .WithParsed(async options =>
                {

                    await httphelper.PostAsync(); } Here the WithParsed method does not actually support async calls but the compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: I will add it as an answer. Too long to explain in a comment. Maybe the problem here.

Comment: I just noticed that If I change
`HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);`
to

`HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`
it seems to work

Comment: I suspect that you don't `await` the `SendInvitation` task. Tasks are supposed to be awaited.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I do await the SendInvitation Task. my code example clearly show me await'ing all async calls.

Comment: The symptoms you describe, and the workaround you had to use, indicates that something somewhere is not awaited.

Comment: It also indicates that there are no remaining threads available to handle the returning task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check whether all calls you make in the code execution path support asynchronousity. For example once I spent quite some time figuring out a nuget package called CommandLineParser did not support async calls. I was using it like so :

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
     Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args) 
                   .WithParsed(async options => 
                    { await httphelper.PostAsync(...); 
                    } 
}
```

I fixed the issue by changing it to something like

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
     Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args) 
                   .WithParsed(options => 
                    { httphelper.PostAsync(...).Result; 
                    } 
}
```

So please check you are not using some calls that do not support async in the way.

Comment: I'm going to say that this answers the problem in that I can get my code working but I'd like to get to the reason async await is not catching exceptions and or dropping tasks

Comment: Indeed, for me also it was not satisfactory to replace the code to run in a synchronous manner. I didn't have time to contribute and fix the issue for the nuget package that I was using, which didn't support async. It is quite a complicated subject and maybe someone more knowledgable in this can explain easily what the problem is. If you find out, I would like to hear more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can **wait for HttpResponseMessage certain condition**. Inspect HttpResponseMessage in debug, with 2 given steps. Screenshot of debug process: [postAsync debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgjTA.png)

1. **return HttpResponseMessage from method** with postAsync:

   ```
    private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> methodWithPostAsync(){
       ...
       response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
       return response
       }
   ```
2. call method and **wait for response message status**:

   ```
   Task<HttpResponseMessage> content= methodWithPostAsync();
   while (!content.IsCompleted)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("busy");
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
   ```

Answer (score -2):

try `ConfigureAwait` like this

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.