# C# Await does not seem to wait for Http server to respond

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, httpclient

In this code snippet:

```
responseMessage = await HttpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

The program ends execution (with exit code 0) as if nothing wrong happened, without continuing from that line. However, from my understanding of await, it should basically block until the method returned the HttpResponseMessage and then continue sequentially.

This code snippet below seems to do what I thought the top one did:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> sendAsyncTask = HttpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

sendAsyncTask.Wait();

responseMessage = sendAsyncTask.Result;
```

Why is this the case? What is wrong with the first code snippet?

Comment: await puts the call on a worker thread, and if the main thread exits, the program execution ends.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă No, it does not do such a thing

Comment: Show the whole program.

Comment: Please give more info how does your code look like from start of the code execution to this point. If you try to await httpclient methods within an execution path that doesn't support async, then this happens.

Comment: Probably same problem as I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59313010/httpclient-postasync-doesn-t-return/59313411#59313411) .

Comment: Do you see any difference in 2 approaches? Are they not executing same way?

Comment: @SirRufo You're right, I was thinking about manually started threads.

Comment: Await doesn't block but returns a Task that will be picked up when the awaited task has a result. But the calling method needs to be async all the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The program ends execution (with exit code 0) as if nothing wrong happened, without continuing from that line.

Most likely, your `Main` method (or some other method in-between `Main` and this one) calls an asynchronous method and then ignores the returned task instead of `await`ing it. Or you have an `async void` somewhere.

> However, from my understanding of await, it should basically block until the method returned the HttpResponseMessage and then continue sequentially.

The entire point of `await` is that it *doesn't* block the caller. `await` does "pause" the method so it can "resume" later, but `await` also *returns* to its caller while the task is in progress. If the caller then exits the application (e.g., by exiting `Main`), then the method never gets a chance to resume because the application is torn down.

Comment: That was the problem! I had a method lower in the stack be a "public async void", but after trying to await that method, I got an error. After doing some searching I found out that void should return Task instead if you intend to await it.